# PDF to Excel '53' error and complete code review

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been tasked with taking PDF documents and turning them into excel files. I have a good base going and I think its close but I keep getting a 53 Run-Time error in a specific area. I am not sure why its not pulling the file name as the file has populated in the pdf_path. Here is the code I have written. Its supposed to pull the file path from 2 cells in the excel sheet and then open them, take the PDF, and convert them into excel. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have tried several variations of .GetFile with no success. Maybe its how it grabbing he file name?

```
Sub PDF_To_Excel()

Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")

Dim pdf_path As String
Dim excel_path As String

pdf_path = setting_sh.Range("E11").Value
excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File

Set fo = fso.GetFile(pdf_path)

Dim wa As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim wr As Object

Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")

wa.Visible = True

Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet

For Each f In fo.Files
    Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
    Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    wr.WholeStory
    
    Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
    Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
    wr.Copy
    
    nsh.Paste
    nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f_Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))
    
    doc.Close False
    nwb.Close False
Next

wa.Quit

MsgBox "DONE"


End Sub
```

Comment: "I keep getting a 53 Run-Time error in a specific area" - in which specific area?

Comment: FYI you have `Dim fo As Folder` but then you call `Set fo = fso.GetFile(pdf_path)`  Did you mean `Set fo = fso.GetFolder(pdf_path)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Changes are marked with `**`

- Get folder object with `GetFolder`
- `For Each f In fo.Files` - `f` is the filename with full path
- `f.Name` is the filename without path

```vb
Sub PDF_To_Excel()
    Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
    Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")
    Dim pdf_path As String
    Dim excel_path As String
    pdf_path = setting_sh.Range("E11").Value
    excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fo As Folder
    Dim f As File
    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(pdf_path) '**
    Dim wa As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim wr As Object
    Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
    wa.Visible = True
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim nsh As Worksheet
    For Each f In fo.Files
        Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f, False, Format:="PDF Files") '**
        Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
        wr.WholeStory
        Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
        Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
        wr.Copy
        nsh.Paste
        nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx")) '**
        doc.Close False
        nwb.Close False
    Next
    wa.Quit
    MsgBox "DONE"
End Sub
```